# Android app won't compile as soon as I create a project

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio

This is my first time trying to create an Android app as I need to do it for college. I've gone onto VS2017 and created a blank android app with Android 7.1, but then without changing anything at all the code just won't build. I'm getting an error saying that "activity_main" is an ambiguous refrence, but I can't find anything else with the same name.

[Android compile error code image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xESjY.png)

Comment: any particular reason you're trying this in c# rather than java?

Comment: @LonelyCpp He uses Xamarin it seems..

Comment: @LonelyCpp I've never coded in java before but have experience in C#. Is java the better language to program in for applications?

Comment: Java or Kotlin are strongly recommended in the context of android development. Have a look around https://developer.android.com/guide/